# tokenizing a string between nested delimiters

Tags: c#, string, tokenize

So, splitting a string based on a delimiter is easy with good 'ol string.split. Now let's say I want to split on an open curly bracket and a closed curly bracket. Also straightforward with:

```
 var foo = "{foo}{bar}";
 var splitme = foo.Split(new char[] { '{', '}'});
```

Now let's make it more complicated by adding nested { } inside the initial opening/closing { }, up to n levels deep. What I'm after is trying to parse a what looks to be proprietary text file format for game mods (stellaris, great game), and I'm looking for a good way to parse this thing. How would I go about preserving each part of the bracketized (tokenized?) piece of a text? Adding to the mix is preserving a key value pair sort of business using an = as the indicator of a relation.

Here is an example of something I'm trying to parse in this fashion:

```
#Neutronium Materials
tech_ship_armor_5 = {
    area = engineering
    cost = @tier3cost4
    tier = 3
    category = { materials }
    ai_update_type = military   
    prerequisites = { "tech_ship_armor_4" "tech_mine_neutronium" }
    weight = @tier3weight4

    weight_modifier = {
        factor = 1.25
        modifier = {
            factor = 1.25
            research_leader = {
                area = engineering
                has_trait = "leader_trait_expertise_materials"
            }
        }
    }

    ai_weight = {
        modifier = {
            factor = 1.25
            research_leader = {
                area = engineering
                has_trait = "leader_trait_expertise_materials"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My first approach was to read this bad boy line by line with a StreamReader, and keep track of how many { I run into before they start getting closed with the corresponding }. Within each chunk of {} I hunt down that = and then figure out my key value pair that I just found, and where it exists in the hierarchy. This... doesn't seem ideal. Is there a better way with some regex magic or an off the shelf text parsing library?

Comment: Use a lexer like ANTLR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would be to look at a JSON parser and see how it's done there.

Your sample looks to be best parsed via recursion: for example, consider `tech_ship_armor_5` to be an object, get its opening tag, verify existence of its closing tag and go from there.

So then you'd have a `tech_ship_armor_5.area` property with a value of `engineering`; the value of the `category` property would then be another object `materials` with properties of its own.

Yep, JSON-like parsing is the way to go with this.

Comment: I like this. Capture ONLY the first and last tag, then take the insides and do the same thing recursively. Good idea. I'll write this up tomorrow morning and may have a couple follow up ?'s, otherwise I think this is the way to go. (plus I'll accept the answer once done writing it up)